# htaccess to block the 'No input file specified.' message

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website with the following structure:
domain.com/directory/subdirectory/index.php

I've noted that when i call for example: domain.com/directory/subdirectory/index.php/example ( **/example** at the end) i see the message 'No input file specified.'

I'va also noted that when i call: domain.com/directory/subdirectory/index.php/ or domain.com/directory/subdirectory/index.php// (slash at the end) i dont' see the message, the page is load but without css!

my question is, it's possibile to block all these kind of wrong request with htaccess?

PS: i use godaddy shared hosting and i have an .htaccess with seo link, like:

```
RewriteRule ^index$ index.php [L]
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this rule on top of all other rules to block all URIs like `/directory/subdirectory/index.php/foo`:

```
RewriteRule (^|/)index\.php.+$ - [L,NC,R=404]
```

Comment: wow, thx! there is a way to use it with all file and not only on index.php? (ex: contactus.php, faq.php,..)

Comment: Yes that is correct: `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php.+$ - [L,NC,R=404]`